# NetSuite: Suitecommerce Theme Issue

Tags: suitecommerce

I want to customize current theme of suitecommerce.
So I tried to fetch current theme.
But I am getting the below issue.

[image]

I tried with several coms but always get an same issue.

Please let me know someone has an experience with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SuiteCommerce occasionally throws this "unexpected error" without providing much context on the specifics of the issue. In this case, it might be related to some missing configuration or issue with the developer tools. If you could provide some more information, that would be really helpful, for example:

- Which version of SuiteCommerce are you using?
- Did you set up the integration record and configure the 2FA tokens?
- Which version of node are you running?
- What is the command you are trying to run?